# How to solve error "You can't specify target table 'users' for update in FROM clause"

Tags: mysql, sql

```
insert into users(email, is_CM, password, username)
    values ('chand122345@gmail.com','N','*****','sidd@12345')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username=(SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = VALUES(username) OR email= VALUES(email));
```

I am trying run this query but I am getting error 
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'users' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

A subquery is not usually used there.  I would expect:

```
insert into users (email, is_CM, password, username)
    values ('chand122345@gmail.com', 'N', '*****',' sidd@12345')
    on duplicate key update username = values(username), email = values(email));
```

This sets the existing row to the values passed into the query.